# User defined method and onStartCommand() in Service class

Tags: android, service

As i read in online tutorials that services are long lasting objects and these are used for long term tasks. Eg. maps, play music in the background etc. i also read some more stuff on services.

To implement bounded service i did following.

In Service class's onStartCommand(), I stated a thread. Inside run() method, i added a loop with 10 iterations. Each iteration takes a sleep of 5000 milliseconds and increaments currentState(int variable) by 1.

There is a method int showThreadStateToClient(). It returns currentState to the MainActivity. Following are two code snippets of Service class. Please tell me what is the difference between them ?

Code snippet 1: (with onStartCommand)

```
public class MyService extends Service {

IBinder iBinder = new LocalBinder();
static int currentState=0;
int totalIterations=10;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return iBinder;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (currentState <= totalIterations) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ++currentState;
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


public class LocalBinder extends Binder
{
    public MyService getService()
    {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}


public int showThreadStateToClient()
{
    return currentState;
}
}
```

Code snippet 2: (without onStartCommand())

```
public class MyService extends Service {

IBinder iBinder = new LocalBinder();
static int currentState=0;
int totalIterations=10;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return iBinder;
}



public class LocalBinder extends Binder
{
    public MyService getService()
    {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

/*this method is called form MainActivity after binding the service.*/
public void startThread()
{
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (currentState <= totalIterations) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ++currentState;
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.start();

}


public int showThreadStateToClient()
{
    return currentState;
}
}
```

Will thread running in code snippet 2 gets all the same rights as the thread running inside onStartCommand() in code snippet 1.

Comment: Anything on `onStartCommand()` will begin to execute as soon as you start the service through `startService(Intent)` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)

Comment: That is ok, as soon as i start service onStartCommand() will run. but this is not anser of my question. i want to know that Will thread running in code snippet 2 gets all the same rights as the thread running inside onStartCommand() in code snippet 1.